# ¿Como mostrar correctamente una fecha en castellano, usando Carbon?

Tags: php, carbon

Aclaro que aunque estoy en un entorno PHP con Eloquent-ORM y usando Carbon para manejar fechas del lado del servidor, NO estoy usando laravel.
Quiero mostrar una fecha en castellano usando Carbon, pero no logro que se muestre en dicho idioma, tengo esto:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
Carbon::setLocale("es");

$fechaCarbon = Carbon::parse($miEgreso->created_at)->toDayDateTimeString();
```

También he probado:

```
$fechaCarbon = Carbon::parse($miEgreso->created_at)->locale("es")->toDayDateTimeString();
```

En ambos casos obtengo algo como:

> "Mon, Jan 4, 2021 4:53 PM"

Cuando espero obtener:

> "Lun, Ene 4, 2021 4:53 PM"

O algo similar donde se interprete que la expresión está en castellano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer Carbon no tiene soporte de localization para muchas de sus funciones nativas, por lo cual hay que hacer una pequeña vuelta para trabajar con las traducciones. En este caso usar isoFormat es una salida. Por ejemplo, si usas:

`now()->locale('es-ES')->isoFormat('ddd ,MMM D, YYYY h:mm a');`

Lo que vendría a ser lo mismo si usas:

`now()->locale('es-ES')->isoFormat('llll');`

Obtendrás como salida: `"lun. ,jun. 21, 2021 5:03 p. m."`

Comment: Pues resultó tu propuesta ... logré lo que quería aunque n como lo esperaba, pero está bien

Comment: A veces sucede... Pero me alegro porque te funcionara.